# PHP fetched result code in JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert2

I'm making a simple delete confirmation prompt with SweetAlert2, PHP and JavaScript. I'm facing a little problem in this code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.delete').click(function() {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showConfirmButton:true,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#49a12f',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        window.location.href = "deleteuser.php?userid=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>";
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
```

with this code, when I click the button it doesn't show anything but the moment I remove this part from the code:

```
<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>
```

everything works and and it redirects but the actual function doesn't work, it won't delete the data I want to delete from the database. I tried to store that PHP code in a variable somehow and use it the other way but no good, I still wasn't able to make changes. Is there any way to put PHP code in JavaScript so that it will run as I would want it to? Thanks in advance.

First thing I'm doing is fetching data from database:

```
<?php

include_once 'connection.php';


$sql="SELECT * FROM admin";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->error){echo "something has gone wrong";}
$result=$stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>
```

Then here's the loop:

```
<tbody class="search">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="profile-img">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="userimg/<?php echo $row["img"]; ?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["firstname"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["lastname"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["phone"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["dept"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["position"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["location"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a class="update" href="update-user.php?userid=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            <div class="deletebut">
                <a class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Under **</ tbody>** I close the loop:

```
<?php
}
 $conn->close();
?>
```

And at the end of the code I use this JavaScript:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.delete').click(function() {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showConfirmButton:true,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#49a12f',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        window.location.href = "deleteuser.php?userid=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>";
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked what the output of the PHP code is, or the error in the console of devtools?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: That means the PHP output is breaking the JS syntax, most likely because of mismatched apostrophes or quotes. Inspect the source output to see what the value is

Comment: window.location.href = "deleteuser.php?userid=<br />

It is outputting this

Comment: There's your problem then :) You need to diagnose why you're seeing a `<br />` tag in the URL instead of the id value.

Comment: Where is the loop that makes: `<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>`

Comment: I've updated the question, you can take a look.

Comment: What is the redirection link.

Comment: Not an answer, but to simplify things, if you aren't using any parameters, you can skip the `->prepare()->execute()` and just run `->query()`. And if you're using mysql, you can use `->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` instead of a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can I think that's what you want.

Example

HTML:

```
<table>
<th>
  <td>column</td>
  <td>op</td>
</th>
<?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
  <td><button class="delete" row_id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">del</button></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  // your confirm dlg
  rowId = $(this).attr('row_id');
  location.href = `deleteuser.php?userid=${rowId}`;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the full code I'm using

Comment: @EPICEXCHANGE you say "Under </ tbody> I close the loop ", why not </ script>?

Comment: I tried to add script before closing loop but then it's giving me two errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at users.php:128
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at users.php:175

and when I click on those two lines there's only a red X and empty line..

Comment: @EPICEXCHANGE Can you import JQ $ ?

Comment: @EPICEXCHANGE stop auto redirect <a  href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete">del</a>

Answer (score -1):

It may be due to PHP waring. Try this.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.delete').click(function() {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showConfirmButton:true,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#49a12f',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        window.location.href = "deleteuser.php?userid=<?php echo !empty($row['id'])?$row['id']:''; ?>";
                    }
                })
            })
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add the code. Also, the issue is more likely to do with the content of `$row['id']`, not the PHP syntax itself

Comment: It seems to be a syntax error, nothing's wrong with PHP code and row is not empty either.